# Shell help text syntax for repeatable group of arguments

Tags: shell, command-line, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, code-documentation

I'm writing a help output for a Bash script. Currently it looks like this:

```
dl [m|r]… (<file>|<URL> [m|r|<index>]…)…
```

The meaning that I'm trying to convey (and elsewhere describe with words) is that (after a potential "`m`" and/or "`r`") there can be an endless list of sets of arguments. The first argument in each set is always a file or URL and the further arguments can each be "`m`", "`r`" or a number. After that, it starts over with a file or URL and so on.

In my special case, I could just write this:

```
dl [m|r]… (<file>|<URL>) (<file>|<URL>|m|r|<index>)…
```

This works, because listing a URL and then another URL with nothing in between is allowed, as well as listing an arbitrarily long chain of "`m`"s (it's just useless to do so) and pretty much any other combination.
But what if that wasn't the case? What if I had for example a command like this:

```
change (<from> <to>)…
```

…which would be used e.g. like this:

```
change from1 to1 from2 to2 from3 to3
```

Would the bracket syntax be correct here? I just guessed it based on the grouping of `(a|b)`, but I wasn't able to find any documentation that uses this for multiple, non-exclusive arguments that belong together. Is there even a standard for this?

Comment: Unless there actually is an official standard for shell help syntax, this probably comes down to a somewhat subjective "best practices" opinion. Should I even mark any answer as accepted then?

Comment: [POSIX utility conventions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) talks a little about the conventions used for syntax description.

Comment: The [usage message Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_message) has a few references, too.

Comment: I actually think this is in an important topic, and that there should be better standards. The convention is usually capitals for symbolic words (`FILE|URL`), square brackets for optional words, and no brackets (and no parentheses) for compulsory words. Your syntax sounds (unnecessarily?) complex, but maybe something like this: `dl [m|r] FILE|URL [m|r|INDEX] ... ...` or this: `dl [m|r] (FILE|URL [m|r|INDEX]) ...`

Comment: @dan Capital:`bandwhich basename blueman-applet cat chown cp date df diff echo ffprobe fold grep head iotop journalctl ls man mkdir mv nano pacman-mirrors pwd readlink shutdown sleep sort stty systemctl tail touch tr wget whoami youtube-dl yt-dlp`. Lowercase:`7z alias base bash chattr complete convert dolphin downgrade exit ffmpeg find free history if kdeconnectd konsole kstart5 kwin_x11 pacman pacman-key pactl read shift shopt source sshpass su sudo tabs tput type umask uptime vlc whereis xdotool xhost yay`. Other:`dir do sed wc`. Even `ffmpeg`/`ffprobe`&`pacman-key`/`pacman-mirrors` differ!

Comment: Improvement idea: `\e[3mITALICS\e[0m`

Comment: @BenjaminW. Combining those two pages and italics, maybe this: `dl [m][r]… [\e[3mFILE\e[0m|\e[3mURL\e[0m [m][r][\e[3mINDEX\e[0m]…]…` Or: `dl [m][r]… [\e[3mFILE\e[0m|\e[3mURL\e[0m] [\e[3mFILE\e[0m|\e[3mURL\e[0m|m|r|\e[3mINDEX\e[0m]…`

Comment: When I see `[m][r]...`, I understand "optional `m`, then optional `r`, and then repeated as often as required", which doesn't make a lot of sense, does it?